# Django Shell API KeyError

Tags: python, django, django-shell

I am importing models in django shell API but i get the below error. Here is how it occurs:

```
python manage.py shell
from .models import Device
```

I get:

`File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"`

Comment: This might be an issue with Python path. What happens if you use absolute import?

Comment: Try from yourappname.models import Device

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try putting the app name before ".models". Here .models trying to import from models.py in the current directory but models.py is actually located in the app directory.

```
>> from [app_name].models import Device
```